# Conceptual connection between observed data and random variables

Tags: random-variables, data-analysis

I am bit confused when trying to connect the concept of realisations of "a" random variable or random variable**s** to the real data observed for the analysis.

For example, the data observed are the measurements of total cholesterol level of 1000 patients, denoted $y_1$, $y_2$,...,$y_{1000}$.

My current understanding is that:

1. Each $y_i$ is a realisation from a single random variable $Y_i$ for $i^{th}$ patient such that $Y_i: \Omega([160, 300])\rightarrow R$. So there are 1000 random variables. The observed data are the realisations from these random variables.
2. In this case, we can talk about convergence of mean total cholesterol level by considering a sequence of random variables $\frac{1}{n}\sum^n_{i=1}{Y_i}$ when number of observations $n\rightarrow\infty$ .
3. The distribution plot such as a histogram or a density plot is in the sense of empirical distribution. Since they are iid random variables, so the distribution from 1000 observations is the empirical distribution where each patient's total cholesterol could come from.

Would this be a proper understanding from an intuitive way?

Comment: Do you have predictors such as height and weight?  Do you want to consider the conditional distribution of $Y_{i}$?  Is it really reasonable to think of the $Y_{i}$ as iid?

Comment: No. I am not considering height and weight. Because when you are given a data, first thing for the analysis is to plot the distribution and summarise the distribution with mean, stand deviation and etc.. Since each measurement was measured from 1000 different patients, they are independent indeed. Since each random variable has a distribution, but the realisation of a single random variable is just a real number. Therefore,  I just want to understand how to conceptually connect the 1000 actual observations to the concept of random variables, and whether my understanding is correct or wrong.